# overriding virtual function on derived class and still invoking base functionality

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, derived

```
class Base
{
    public:
    void virtual func() {   int i = 0; cout << "i"; }
}

class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
    void func() {  .....******   }
}
```

In the derived class, when you call func from a derived object, how do you still have the base functionality when func is already overriden. Can you just call Base.func()? Thanks before

Comment: Have you tried using `Base.func()`?

Comment: @nhgrif not yet, thus the question. haha

Comment: You can do `derived.Base::func()`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `::` to call an overridden base class virtual function from a derived class function.

```
Base::func()
```